# A required library with LAPACK API not found. Please specify library location

Tags: compiling, libraries, cmake

I’m trying to install ESTER and I keep getting this error message. I've already installed BLAS and LAPACK libraries. Any ideas?

```
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/usr
-- A library with BLAS API found.
-- A library with BLAS API found.
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindLAPACK.cmake:342 (message):
  A required library with LAPACK API not found.  Please specify library
  location.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:41 (find_package)
```

Comment: Did you install the `liblapack-dev` package?

Comment: Example Ubuntu 18.04, with `libatlas-base-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev libhdf5-dev` → no "cmake issues". ....  Note : "libatlas-base-dev" provides the **cblas** https://github.com/ester-project/ester/wiki/Install

Comment: Ey thanks for your help. Yes, Ive already installed all of those.

Comment: I also get this                  Looking for Fortran cheev - not found